# Adding a foreign server's self-signed certificate to the trusted certificates of my Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate, tomcat6

My Tomcat needs to connect to **another** web server (at https://foreign.example.com) using SSL (TLS).

foreign.example.com has a self-signed certificate, which I trust. Of course, my Tomcat does not by default - so I have to tell it. One way to do this is:

```
$JRE/bin/keytool -import -alias my -file ssl-cert-myselfsigned.cer -keystore 
 $JRE/lib/security/cacerts
```

*This works*: My Tomcat allows the SSL connection.

However, I *don't like to do it this way*: It imports the certificate into the trusted keys of my Java installation. I don't want to say: "Every application that runs Java on my machine should trust that certificate". Only Tomcat (or the user that runs Tomcat) should trust it.

So I tried importing it into the tomcat-user's keystore at `~/.keystore`, and setting up Tomcat's `<Connector>` with these attributes:

```
keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore"
keystorePass="thePassphraseICreatedTheKeystoreWith"
```

However, that doesn't work at all (I believe, this is only for the server certificate of my Tomcat, not for server certificates of foreign servers, right?)

I tried the same with the `truststoreFile`/`truststorePass` attributes, but they didn't work either. (The attributes are documented at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)

Is there a way to set up Tomcat with the foreign server's server cert, or maybe to add some command line parameters to `java` which makes my keystore (and keystore passphrase) available to the JVM instance?

Comment: Can you clarify what doesn't work if you make a copy of "$JRE/lib/security/cacerts", import your specific cert into it and use the truststoreFile/truststorePass attributes? It should work. (And yes, the "keystore keystore" is for your credentials, not how you trust remote certificates.)

Comment: @Bruno: Ah, looking into the (very extensive) logs, I see that I'm getting `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must not be empty` - which means, that it didn't find the truststore file... I wonder, if maybe `${user.home}` doesn't work in this place?

Comment: Sorry, I should have realised this earlier, but the `truststore` parameters only dictate the behaviour of the connector (i.e. for client-certs). When you say "My Tomcat needs to connect to another web server", I guess your webapp is the client, not the container (and definitely not the connector). The trust config will change depending on the client lib. The default `SSLContext` (which it's likely to use if nothing else is specified) is configured via the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property. If you want a more local configuration, we'd need to know which client library you're using.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks a lot! This clarified it - the trustStore can't be configured in the Connector. Using the command line parameters - together with your method of copying cacerts and adding the keys there - works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JBoss (which is based on Tomcat) can be run with the following cmd arguments. The cacerts file (or however you would like to name it) must contain the cert of the endpoint.

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Applications\jboss-as\server\default\conf\cacerts 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

Therefor this should also work for Tomcat.

Comment: Yes, good find. These parameters work with my little Java test application I use to simulate the connection (because it's a lot quicker than restarting the server each time :-) But I haven't been able to make it work with my server yet. (Note: If the trustStorePassword should not leak to other users on the system, it would be better not to specify it on the command line - command lines of running processes can be read easily with `ps ax` (on a Unix system).)

Comment: Fully agree but on my test machine with dummy certificates, I don't care ;-)

Comment: Confirming, that this also works with my setup :-) And thinking about it: As long as I only put public certificates into my truststore, and make it non-writable by other users, I'm safe. (I will rename the file to make it clear, that I must never put  private keys in it!) Actually, the storePassword is completely superfluous in this situation.

Comment: @Chris Lercher @rit you don't need to specify the truststore password at all. All it does is enable a verify step. You aren't getting anything secret out of it. In fact there is nothing secret about a truststore at all, it just contains public certificates.

Comment: @EJB That's exactly right; just make sure, that the file can't be changed by untrusted users. However, Java's `keytool` (at least by default) doesn't allow to create a keystore without a password. In fact, it requires that it's at least 6 chars long. I'm not sure: Maybe there's a way to convince it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to add it to the SSL connector in tomcat in your tomcat server.xml file.  Specifically you need to set the truststoreFile properties to enable trust of certificates from other servers.

```
        <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="../../../deploy/tomcat/config/ssl/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"
               truststoreFile="../../../deploy/tomcat/config/ssl/keystore.jks" truststorePass="changeit"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, but as mentioned in the question (and in the comments), this did not work - at least not back then, when I asked the question. Did the meaning of the truststoreFile attribute change since Tomcat 6.0?