# Spring remoting using Https and tomcat

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, spring-remoting

My application is a swing based client communicating to tomcat using spring remoting Http invoker, I want to convert to https.

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [https://localhost:8443/aten_server/metadataservice/MetaDataService-httpinvoker]; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:212)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:145)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy4.getMemberStatuses(Unknown Source)
        at com.kantarmedia.panelmanager.presenters.AbstractPresenter.(AbstractPresenter.java:114)
        at com.kantarmedia.panelmanager.presenters.MainPanelPresenter.(MainPanelPresenter.java:28)
        at com.kantarmedia.panelmanager.PanelManagerFactory.(PanelManagerFactory.java:135)
        at com.kantarmedia.panelmanager.PanelManagerApp.startup(PanelManagerApp.java:32)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:642)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:612)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:502)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executePostMethod(CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:196)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:130)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
        ... 50 more
```

My client side spring config file is

```
<bean id="memberDataServiceHttpInvokerProxy" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="#{systemProperties['aten.protocol']}://#{systemProperties['aten.host']}:#{systemProperties['aten.port']}/aten_server/memberdataservice/MemberDataService-httpinvoker"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.kantar.server.panel.services.IMemberDataService"/>
        <property name="httpInvokerRequestExecutor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor" />
        </property>
</bean>
```

Please help me to sort out problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't Spring Remoting, it's that the certificate on the server you are accessing is not signed by a CA or trusted certificate - you need to add this certificate to your keystore.

See [Adding a foreign server's self-signed certificate to the trusted certificates of my Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497183/adding-a-foreign-servers-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-certificates-of) for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means you use SSL/HTTPS. Please check your certificate, seems it is not installed or invalid